# Collapsible magento layered navigation

Tags: php, jquery, magento

did anyone know to make `magento layered navigation collapse and expand`

i found this code but i am not sure to do with jquery with the dd dt class

```
<dl id="narrow-by-list">
    <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
    <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
        <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
            <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dd").hide();
        jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dt").click(function(){
            jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dd:visible").slideUp("fast");
            jQuery(this).next("dd").slideToggle("fast");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Include jQuery library in your theme (you might have to use NoConflict Mode)
2) Modify template/category/layer/view.phtml file in your theme in a following way.

A) Change `<dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>`

to `<dt><a href="/"><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></a></dt>`

As you see, we wrapper the attribute filter name in the  so it becomes clickable link.

B) then include the jquery code snippet in the same view.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dd:not(:first)").hide();
jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dt a").click(function(){
jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dd:visible").slideUp("fast");
jQuery(this).parent().next().slideDown("fast");
return false;
});
});
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dd").show();
jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dt").click(function(){
jQuery(this).next("dd").slideToggle("slow");
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think, Anisha shaikh's answer is helpful for someone... ::)